# Need an approach to create Audit tables while processing streaming data for batch records at an instance

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-emr

I am **trying to create an audit framework for streaming data** in which I need 3 audit tables batch_log, step_log and error_log. These tables should capture the live state of streaming data which will be processed by EMR. Storage service used is RedShift.

**Batch log table:** This table is responsible to capture live status of the the batch records(BR) that are being processed by the EMR cluster runs in multiple Redshift clusters.

Columns in batch_log table - batch_id(PK), batch_start_time, batch_end_time, source_system, target_system, cluster1_count, cluster2_count, cluster3_count, cluster4_count, batch_status.

**Step log table:** This table is responsible to capture final status of multiple logical steps that are part of single BR processed by EMR Cluster in different Redshift clusters. For example - retrieve table_configuration.json is one step, read data from source is another step and etc.

Columns in step_log table - step_id(PK), batch_id(FK), step_start_time, step_end_time and step_status.

**Error log table:** This table is responsible to capture the error details that occurred due to step failure in the BR processing.

Columns in error_log table - error_id(PK), step_id(FK), error_type, error_code and error_message.

**Note:**

1. PK = Primary Key
2. FK = Foreign Key
3. BR = Batch Records
4. A single batch_id will have multiple step_ids.
5. Unsure on the table-wise log capture at this point of framework developmnet.

**Limitations:** I can use only pyspark coding in EMR cluster runs to capture this audit tables information.

Is this possible? If so, what is the better way to implement this framework?
If not pyspark what is a better solution to implement this kind of framework?
If not this audit tables via pyspark, is there a better process/automated process/tool- that can be integrated with AWS EMR?

**Purpose of this requirement/audit framework:** Need a single place where business/layman can check the live status and point where data is during the streaming data process by EMR.

Please help out with your knowledge.